# Issue occuring in ECM 2.1 installation on 7.2 Version

Tags: ecm

I am trying to install E-mail Campaign Manager 2.1 rev. 140214 but I am unable to do so because of the fact that "InvalidItemNameChars" attribute value contains - (hyphen).

The setting is as below:

```
<setting name="InvalidItemNameChars" value="\/:?"<>|[]-"/>
```

I would like to know if there is a workaround for installing this package.

Please help us in installation. For information, we are using 7.2 rev. 150408 and ECM 2.1. I know it is old version but still trying to find some solution.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this is using hypen in InvalidItemNameChars.

Remember default value of the InvalidItemNameChars is `"\/:?&quot;&lt;&gt;|[]"`. With this value the ECM package can be installed. So you can use following steps.

- Remove the dash from your InvalidItemNameChars and set the default
  value.
- Install the module package.
- Set the InvalidItemNameChars back
  to your value.